# What is the right way to write a razor form so that the model correctly binds to the form POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I sometimes find myself writing razor for forms like the following:

```
<h2>Subscription form for @Model.UserName</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Subscribe", "Subscribe", FormMethod.Post)
{
   @Html.Partial("CreditCardForm", Model.PaymentInfo)
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PaymentInfo.PromoCode)
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PaymentInfo.PromoCode, new{Name="PromoCode"})

   <button type=submit>Submit</button>
}
```

The CreditCardForm partial is reused in a different view (i.e. to update credit card details) and in that case, the PromoCode is not needed, hence why it's pulled out in this way. This might look like the following:

```
<h2>Update Credit Card form for @Model.UserName</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateCreditCard", "Subscribe", FormMethod.Post)
{
   @Html.Partial("CreditCardForm", Model.PaymentInfo)

   <button type=submit>Submit</button>
}
```

The other thing to note here is that the model used in these views have two properties: UserName and PaymentInfo; UserName is a display-only property and PaymentInfo is a model that is to be posted back.

Note the override of the name attribute of the PromoCode property at the bottom so that the PromoCode value is correctly bound to the model that is posted back to the controller action. Leaving it as it is would mean that the PromoCode editor has the default name of PaymentInfo.PromoCode which does not bind correctly to the model.

The action method that the form posts to looks like the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Subscribe(PaymentInfo paymentInfo)
    {
        ...
    }
```

This has always felt like a hack to me - is there a better/right way to do this?

Comment: You should not attempt to override the `name` attribute. You post back your model you use in the view, not a property of your model (but you use of `Html.Partial()` is also incorrect - the correct usage is an `EditorTempate`)

Comment: And it does not generate a _"default name of PaymentInfo_PromoCode"_ - the default is `name="PaymentInfo.PromoCode"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke What happens if there is additional data that you want to display on a page which has a form that is not needed or part of a form post? It seems a bit limiting that we always have to post back the model that is used in the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Also: what's is there a difference between using a partial and an editor template in this context?

Comment: The as always, use a view model that represents what you want to display/edit in the view.

Comment: A `EditorTemplate` will correctly name your form controls with the prefix (a  partial will not unless you pass the `HtmlFieldPrefix` as additional `ViewData`) but it appears you only want to post back a property of your model (not generally recommended because of issues with returning the view if `ModelState` is invalid) but you can always use the `[Bind(Prefix = "PaymentInfo")]` attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke I confused the default name with the id. I've edited the question now so it correctly reflects the name as it is generated. Cheers!

Comment: _"which does not bind correctly to the model"_ - what @Stephen said, then you need to specify the proper type (or "model") in the action method's parameters. If not asked before, this can become a good question, but you need to include all your comments (and actual models, views and action methods that represent the issue) in your question. The answer then lies somewhere between "use a display model and edit model" and/or "use inheritance".

Comment: Thanks guys. I've added a bit more info to hopefully provide more context. As I am typing this, one issue that I didn't realise I had was the fact that I have a model that have both properties for view and properties that are posted back. Potentially, a resolution to that is to implement the view-only parts of the page as child actions?

Comment: I'm still wondering what's the best way to resolve my original issue however: how do I reuse CreditCardForm and have an additional field for PromoCode for one of the forms that use it? Not sure if implementing it as an EditorTemplate would solve it for this specific case because the model is binding correctly - it was only PromoCode that wasn't coming across without my hack.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep Promocode out of your PaymentInfo model. More standard as per MVC.

```
public class SubscribeModel
{
   public string UserName {get;set;}
   public string PromoCode {get;set;}
   public PaymentInfo PaymentInfo {get;set;}
}

public class UpdateCreditCardModel
{
   public PaymentInfo PaymentInfo {get;set;}
}

public class PaymentInfo
{
   //Payment Info Properties goes here.
}
```

Subscriber View

```
<h2>Subscription form for @Model.UserName</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Subscribe", "Subscribe", FormMethod.Post)
{
   @Html.Partial("CreditCardForm", Model.PaymentInfo)
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PromoCode)
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PromoCode)

   <button type=submit>Submit</button>
}
```

In your controllers

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Subscribe(SubscribeModel model)
    {
       //Access model.Promocode and model.PaymentInfo here.
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateCreditCard(UpdateCreditCardModel model)
    {
       //Access model.PaymentInfo here.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a hack.  You are completely fighting against the framework, which provides mechanisms to do exactly what you want to do.  They're called EditorTemplates.

Partials and EditorTemplates are similar, but only EditorTemplates create the proper form names to support model binding automatically.  Partials do not, at least not in the way you are using them.

Convert your partial to an EditorTemplate, and then just accept your parent model in your post action.